# How to Print /PDF entire page

Tags: 7, files

I was wondering if the [Print](http://drupal.org/project/print) module can be used to print an entire page, not just nodes. I need to add some blocks to the pdf as well, not just the node content.

Is there any way of doing this, or will I need to manually add the blocks to the `node->content` property?

LATER EDIT: The problem is that the print module takes the node ID as a parameter. This means I cannot print *blocks* on those pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can show blocks by tweaking templates. See [FAQs in the project documentation](http://drupal.org/node/190173) specifically the entry on [blocks](http://drupal.org/node/190173#contentblocks).

It says there: add the following to your print.tpl.php template:

```
  print render(block_get_blocks_by_region('content'));
```

**Update** The FAQ also has an entry on [Views support](http://drupal.org/node/190173#views). It's doable - have just tested with Drupal 7.20 and [Print 7.x-1.2](http://drupal.org/project/print). You have to add the paths to the non-nodes you want in Configuration. There's also a useful point on Views support and hiding the print link on your print out when using Views in the comments on the FAQ page, so worth rooting around there. Don't forget to enable the block to show the print / email / PDF links.

Comment: thanks for that. Apparently it works for all regions except for the `content` one :)) I'll try creating a new template, maybe this will help

Comment: but the problem is that the links (print/nid, printpdf/nid) requires a node ID parameter. this means I cannot print view pages :(

Comment: Again - take a good look at the Documentation for the module and also work through the configuration pages. Just tested with Views and it works fine. Updated answer to explicitly mention Views.

Comment: I will accept this answer but still doesn't solve my problem: adding blocks from the *content* region to a pdf.

Comment: I know this is an old issue, but be sure to check your print.css. It could be hiding those blocks from you.

Answer (score 1):

There is a block version of print links `Printer, email and PDF versions`. goto `admin/structure/block` and enable it. next you should goto `admin/config/user-interface/print` and change `Printer-friendly page link` setting to `Block`.

Comment: it sill adds just the node content, no additional blocks are added to the pdf version :(